# Providing readonly value in twig file returns null in symfony3.2

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

In my application form updation twig is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{form_label(formUser.name)}} :
   <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value="{{formUser.name.vars.value}}" type="text">
   <input id="appbundle_user_name" name="appbundle_user[name]" value="{{formUser.name.vars.value}}" type="hidden">
</div>
```

It returns null value when updating the form how to solve this issue,to get the output?

Comment: What exactly in these five lines "returns null value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disabled is not the same as readonly, it will not be included in the POST variables if that is where the value is null.